# Concatenate two integers in Spring EL

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I want to create a Spring EL in which I want that two integers be concatenated as `a-b` with `a` and `b` being integers. Spring EL does not support `concat` function with integers as they are not `String`s. I have tried to cast them like `#T(java.lang.String).valueOf(user.id).concat('-').concat(#T(java.lang.String).valueOf(user.serviceId))` but this is not working.

What should be the correct expression?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please, use next expression `#{T(java.lang.String).format('%d-%d', user.id, user.serviceId)}`. 
Hope this helps.

**Update.**

If this expression will be used within `@Cacheable(key)` field, please update expression in next way: `T(java.lang.String).format('%d-%d', #user.id, #user.serviceId)`.

Comment: That did not work. I replaced it: `@Cacheable(value = "resolvedFeedbacks", key = "#{T(java.lang.String).format('%d-%d', user.id, user.serviceId)}")` and I got this error: `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1043E:(pos 1): Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lcurly({)'`

Comment: Try to remove "#{" and "}" from expression, but add "#" to "user".

Answer (score 0):

I added it and it really works in java spring booot caches:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = ALL_CLASS_MKTU_BY_RESH_DATA, key = "{T(java.lang.String).format(\"%d-%d-%d\",#id,#year,#type)}")
public List<String> findAll(int id, int year, int type) {
```

//
}